# Set the border of a subclassed NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstablecellview

As mentioned in the title of this post I want to set the border (color and width) of a subclassed `NSTableCellView` which is used inside a view-based `NSTableView`. I tried the following

```
self.layer.borderColor = [[NSColor greenColor] CGColor];
self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
```

I placed the code in `initWithCoder` and `awakeFromNib` without the desired result. Changing the `backgroundColor` is possible within the `drawRect`-Method. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is my solution using `NSFrameRect`

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

    [[NSColor lightGrayColor]set];
    NSFrameRect([self bounds]);

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views on OS X are not layer backed by default. You first need to setWantsLayer: YES

But if you are using drawRect: you can just use NSFrameRect() or one of the similar functions or draw with an NSBezierPath in you cell view subclass. However, keep in mind that usually the row view does background drawing in view based tables.

Sounds like you have a bit of learning yet to do about drawing in Cocoa.

Comment: setWantsLayer:YES was what I'm searching for. Btw in the meanwhile I solved the issue also using a NSBezierPath.

Comment: Core Animation layers change the world dramatically in Cocoa views. I recommend sticking to AppKit drawing with a bezier path or AppKit function unless you know you need to go layer-backed to really do more CA things. For a table view it's likely you don't need it.